# Increase height on hover and push elements top and bottom

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have 3 equal elements on the page (33.333% height each), when the user hovers over one of the elements I would like the height of that element to grow to 100%.

The first section works as I'd like it to, the 2nd section I would like it to grow from the top and bottom, pushing the elements above and below off of the screen - I can do this with absolute positioning, but then the elements above and below stay in the same place and the element grows over them (with the right z-index).

I've tried scaling the element, and using borders that increase/decrease, however I will be using background images and potentially videos so this won't work.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have currently:

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.home-split {
    height: 100vh;
}

.home-split .item {
    height: 33.333%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.home-split .item:hover {
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 9990;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.home-split .item .title {
    align-self: center;
}

.home-split .item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-split .item a h2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.home-split .item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #000;

}

.home-split .item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.home-split .item:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<section class="home-split">

  <div class="row no-gutters item">

    <div class="col-12 text-center h-100">
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row no-gutters item">

    <div class="col-12 text-center h-100">
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Item 2</h2>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row no-gutters item">

    <div class="col-12 h-100">
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Item 3</h2>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>


</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d81mxuL5/

Answer (score 0):

You need a less specific selector to hide all sections when the outer container is hovered:

```
.home-split:hover .item {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This just shrinks the other elements though, I need the elements to be pushed off the screen. So in the first item in the jsfiddle is actually pushes the other elements down. I'd like the middle one to push the top one up and the bottom one down and then the bottom one would push the top two up

Answer (score 0):

friend I use JQuery to achive

```js
$(".item").hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings().css( "height", "1px");
        $(this).css( "height", "98%");
    }, function() {
         $(this).siblings().css( "height", "33%");
          $(this).css( "height", "33%");
    });
```

```css
body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.home-split {
 height: 100vh;
}

.home-split .item {
 height: 33.333%;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 1s;
 z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.home-split .item:hover {
 height: 100%;
 transition: all 1s;
 z-index: 9990;
 top: 0 !important;
}

.home-split .item .title {
 align-self: center;
}

.home-split .item a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-split .item a h2 {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.home-split .item:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: #000;

}

.home-split .item:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.home-split .item:nth-child(3) {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home-split">

      <div class="row no-gutters item">
        <div class="col-12 text-center h-100">
          <a href="#">
            <h2>Item 1</h2>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row no-gutters item">

        <div class="col-12 text-center h-100">
          <a href="#">
            <h2>Item 2</h2>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row no-gutters item">

        <div class="col-12 h-100">
          <a href="#">
            <h2>Item 3</h2>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>


    </section>
```